# Stopwatch weird behavior

Tags: c#, stopwatch

```
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.Start();
                fn(); //call function
                sw.Stop();

            }
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            long total =0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                fn(); //call function
                sw.Stop();
                total += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            }
            Console.WriteLine(total);
```

The output is not the same, do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: For any reasonable length fn() (one worth profiling), the overhead associated with a loop is going to be negligible and, in any case, less than the overhead associated with Start and Stop.  For one thing, Start and Stop both have method call overhead (assuming no inlining), whereas a simple for loop is just an increment and comparison branch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leaving aside things like the fact that you're creating loads of objects in the second loop, which could easily cause garbage collection within `fn()` or something else to *actually* make it take longer while timing, you're also just taking the elapsed *milliseconds* each iteration in the second case.

Suppose each iteration takes 0.1 milliseconds. Your total for the second loop would be 0, because on each iteration it would round down the elapsed time to 0 milliseconds. The first loop keeps track of the elapsed *ticks*.

Leaving all this aside, you shouldn't be starting and stopping the timer this frequently anyway - it *will* mess with your results. Instead, start the stopwatch once before the loop, and stop it after the loop.

If you want to take out the overhead of the looping, simply time an *empty* loop to find the overhead, and subtract that from the time taken with a loop containing actual work. Now it's not really *quite* that simple, because of the various complexities of real world CPUs - things like cache misses - but microbenchmarking is frankly *never* particularly accurate in that respect. It should be used as a guide more than anything else.

Comment: This is quite old now  but I think it's worth noting that the typical use of a stopwatch here would be to start *before* the loop and stop *after* the loop then divide by the iterations (lines.Length) to get the average time of fn(). Assuming the number of iterations is high this should be fairly accurate given the low overhead of looping and you don't have issues with stopwatch granularity for very fast functions.

Comment: @Lummo: I've added a sentence to that effect.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `StartNew()` and `Stop()` create overhead. That's the reason you normally do these kinds of tests with 100s or 1000s of iterations: to minimize the performance overhead of the actual performance measurements.

Comment: I think the problem is due to loosing resolution as Skeet mentioned

Comment: The creation is outside the measured code (start on the stopwatch is the last thing done in StartNew), hence does not affect the timer. Resolution and rounding on the other side seems to be the cause. The correct answer seems to be Jon Skeets answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4088847/95008).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into the granularity of the system timer. Sometimes timing a trivial function will return 0 or 10 ms. This error could be adding up on your test.

You would probably see a similar result if you ran the first loop twice or the second loop twice as well.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead of the loop is going to be considerably smaller than the overhead of stopping/starting the timer repeatedly and even less so in the case of creating a new one repeatedly. As such, I'd start the timer before the loop and end it after the loop and divide your elapsed time by the number of iterations. It's going to give you far more accurate results.

Comment: that is true, but I wanna to measure only my function performance

Comment: Then, as Jon said, measure an empty loop and subtract from this measurement.